# How is a json paginated resource supposed to look like?

Tags: ember.js, pagination, ember-data, ember-cli, json-api

With Ember Data and Jsonapi. How is a json paginated resource supposed to look like?

I built my response so it looks like:

```
"meta": {
  "page": {
    "number": 1,
    "size": 5,
    "total": 39
  }
},
"links": {
  "self": "http://localhost:3099/api/v1/articles",
  "prev": null,
  "next": "http://localhost:3099/api/v1/articles?page[number]=2",
  "first": "http://localhost:3099/api/v1/articles?page[number]=1",
  "last": "http://localhost:3099/api/v1/articles?page[number]=39"
},
"data": [
  ...
]
```

But I am not exactly sure if this is the right format. based on the explanation at http://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-pagination

Or, are the pagination links (i.e. `prev`, `next`, `first` and `last`) supposed to be in `meta.page` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ember-cli-pagination](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-pagination) and its format to do pagination. I'm pretty sure Ember Data does *not* follow the JSON API spec strictly.

Based on your sample this could be a format:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "total_pages": 3,
    "page": 1
  },

  "articles": [
    {"id": 1, "title": "Hello World", "body": "More to Come"},
    // ......
  ]
}
```

The request URL of this payload could be `http://localhost:3099/api/v1/articles?page=1`. See the API for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Ember Data doesn't follow the JSON spec strictly so you should concentrate more on setting up the JSON with what ED needs.  I would personally move the 'links' info into the meta tag.  Otherwise Ember-Data will attempt to put them into a model called 'links', which may not be what you want.  If you do intend to store those inside a separate 'links' model, then what you have is fine.